# What happens if you do not replace a damaged steering rack boot\gaiter?

Tags: repair

The boot\gaiter on my steering rack is loose and can be moved left and right so dirt and water can get in.  It has been like this for at least 5 months.

What damages might have happened or will happen if you leave it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end up having to replace the rack -:

Gaiter is cheap to replace,

Rack is more expensive...

Your money your choice...

Answer (score 0):

the boots on the steering rack or similar to the boots on the axles in that they are there to prevent dust dirt and grime from getting into the joints and seals and tearing them up and ruining the components.  A little bit of grit can easily ruin the seals at each end of the steering rack.